# Stream mobile navigation from my android phone to my PC(host) using smartdevicelink

Tags: android, smartdevicelink

I am developing an android app to stream my phone navigation to Linux PC where I am running the SDL core and SDL HMI.
I am using TCP to communicate between PC and my app. This communication is established using steps mentioned in the below mentioned link: 
https://smartdevicelink.com/en/guides/android/getting-started/hello-sdl-android/
It would be really helpful if someone can provide few references on how to implement Mobile Navigation for Android. I tried to look for some examples but only found it for iOS, not Android.

Comment: What do you mean by "Mobile Navigation for android"?

Comment: Mobile Navigation is one of the features provided by SmartDeviceLink https://smartdevicelink.com/en/guides/iOS/mobile-navigation/introduction/#

Comment: I wanted to use this feature so that I can stream my phone navigation to my PC. Currently I have found reference only for iOS, I needed it for android.